# ¿Como poner un color de fondo sobre una etiqueta img?

Tags: html, css

Quiero aplicarle un color de fondo sobre la imagen, lo he intentado de la siguiente manera:

```
img::before {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(44,62,80, 7), rgba(44,62,80, 7));
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

<div class="carousel-item active">
  <img class="d-block w-100" src="/img/games/bg.jpg" alt="" width="800" height="550" />
</div>
```

Pero no funciona, ¿Como podría resolverlo?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner también tu HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La manera en que aplico yo los overlays es de la siguiente manera:

Envuelto todo en un contenedor cualquiera y aplico estos estilos:

```
.imagen::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.imagen {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/dmkp3aw0/)

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba xD

Answer (score 1):

Ponle una clase, tal vez al div o a la sección ponle el

```
.section {   
   Background-color: #000;
 }
```